# AD/LDAP authentication for FitNesse

Tags: ldap, fitnesse

We are going to put FitNesse on a server and wants to have a AD/LDAP authentication solution for this.
Does anyone have experience with good and easy to set up solutions for this?

Thanks in advance. Magnus

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward method would be to download the standard edition of the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) and get a copy of the `jsse.jar` file and install both jar files in the fitness lib directory. Create a class in the `fitness.authentication` package that extends the `fitness.authentication.Authenticator` class and overrides the `isAuthenticated()` method. Specify the required properties such as hostname, port, simple or SASL bind, whether to use SSL or StartTLS, base object, search scope, and so forth.

The `jsse.jar` will provide the necessary SSL classes so that SSL and StartTLS can be implemented as required.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it would require either finding or creating a plugin to do it.

I found the following, but I have never tried it:

- https://github.com/timander/fitnesse-ldap-authenticator.

Also out there, but older is: https://github.com/dleonard0/fitnesse

You can start there, but you might have to get your hands dirty.  Unfortunately, I'm just not that familiar with that part of the code.

Comment: Don't forget SSL if using @timander's solution - http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.NetworkSecurity

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.SecurityDescription.SpnegoAuthentication

I need to give many more characters to make stakeoverflow happy.

Comment: This link is dead. Can you please provide different link.